# How to make the following substitution in string using regex in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a substitution in the following string:

```
poem='''
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the aching,
Or cool one pain,
Or help one fainting robin
Unto his nest again,
I shall not live in vain.
'''
```

The requirement are as below in the given string:

1. If the pattern has characters 'ai' or 'hi', replace the next three characters with `*\*`.
2. If a word has 'ch' or 'co', replace it with 'Ch' or 'Co'.

I tried the following methods:

```
print(re.sub(r"ai\w{3}|hi\w{3}",r"(ai|hi)*\*",poem))
```

**Output:**

```
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the aching,
Or cool one pain,
Or help one f(ai|hi)*\*ng robin
Unto his nest again,
I shall not live in vain.

print(re.sub(r"ch|co",r"Ch|Co",poem))
```

**Output:**

```
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the aCh|Coing,
Or Ch|Cool one pain,
Or help one fainting robin
Unto his nest again,
I shall not live in vain.
```

You can see the output is not as per the requirements. Please help me find the correct regex expression.

Answer (score 1):

The first you can achieve by referencing a captured group from the pattern in the replacement:

```
poem = re.sub(r"(ai|hi)\w{3}", "\g<1>*\*", poem)
```

For the second, you can pass a function as replacement (see [the `re.sub` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

```
def title(match):
    return match.group(0).title()  # or .capitalize()

poem = re.sub(r"ch|co", title, poem)
```

Comment: not sure if applicable - but `vain;` is not matched due to missing `re.DOTALL` - wich might be wanted - or not.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah, not sure. "the following 3 characters" is vague here :) I assume there have to be 3 alphanumeric characters, given the OP's attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace those step wise:

```
poem='''
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the aching,
Or cool one pain,
Or help one fainting robin
Unto his nest again,
I shall not live in vain.
'''

import re

p2 = re.sub("(?:ai|hi)...","*/*",poem)
p3 = re.sub("ch","Ch",p2)
p4 = re.sub("co","Co",p3)

print(p4)
```

Output:

```
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the ac*/*
Or Cool one pain,
Or help one f*/*ng robin
Unto */*est again,
I shall not live in vain.
```

The only interesting thing is a non-capturing group around ai|hi that does not work as I expected - ai and hi are still replaced. You might want to change them to:

```
p = re.sub("ai...","*/*",poem, flags = re.DOTALL)
p2 = re.sub("hi...","*/*",p, flags= re.DOTALL)
p3 = re.sub("ch","Ch",p2)
p4 = re.sub("co","Co",p3)

print(p4)
```

Output:

```
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in v*/*If I can ease one life the ac*/*
Or Cool one p*/*Or help one f*/*ng robin
Unto */*est ag*/*I shall not live in v*/*
```

The [flag `re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) lets `.` also match newline characters.
Without it, `vain;` would not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
poem = re.sub(r'(ai|hi)(...)', r'\1*\*', poem)
poem = re.sub('ch', 'Ch', poem)
poem = re.sub('co', 'Co', poem)
print(poem)
```

This outputs:

```
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the aChi*\*
Or Cool one pain,
Or help one fai*\*ng robin
Unto hi*\*est again,
I shall not live in vain.
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(re.sub(r"co",r"Co",re.sub(r"ch",r"Ch",s)))`

This works:

```
Input:

    s='''It takes strength for being certain,
    It takes courage to have doubt.
    It takes strength for challenging alone,
    It takes courage to lean on another.
    It takes strength for loving other souls,
    It takes courage to be loved.
    It takes strength for hiding our own pain,
    It takes courage to help if it is paining for someone.'''

    Output:
    It takes strength for being certain,
    It takes Courage to have doubt.
    It takes strength for Challenging alone,
    It takes Courage to lean on another.
    It takes strength for loving other souls,
    It takes Courage to be loved.
    It takes strength for hiding our own pain,
    It takes Courage to help if it is paining for someone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to your question:
    `import re`

```
poem='''
If I can stop one heart from breaking,
I shall not live in vain;
If I can ease one life the aching,
Or cool one pain,
Or help one fainting robin
Unto his nest again,
I shall not live in vain.
'''`

p1=poem
print(re.sub(r"\n","",poem))
poem=re.sub(r"co","Co",poem)
poem=re.sub(r"ch","Ch",poem)
print(poem)
print(re.sub(r"ai|hi{3}","*/*",p1))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` which acts as `or` to mention options and create groups using `()` to match and retain some of the groups by using `\<group number>` (1-indexed) in replace string

For first one you can make 2 groups to match `(hi|ai)` and to match next 3 characters like `(...)` and then replace only second group and retain the first group using `\1`

```
print(re.sub(r'(hi|ai)(...)', r'\1*\*', poem))
```

For second one you can make 2 groups to match `(c)` and `(h|o)` and retain second group  using `\2`

```
print(re.sub(r'(c)(h|o)', r'C\2', poem))
```